# Is there a way to stretch a grid item over the grid gap?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a container and a child

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .child {
  grid-column: 1/ 4;
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to bring the `.child` next to column 5 (so to column 4 plus the `20px`)

Comment: I believe this is the absolutely correct behavior. Have you tried just adding `margin-left: -20px` to the child?

Comment: @MichałSadowski that worked! in my case I needed `margin-right: -20px`. I didn't even think it would work. I thought it would just move rather than stretch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Gutters) :

> In terms of grid sizing, gaps act as if they were a regular grid track however nothing can be placed into the gap. The gap acts as if the grid line at that location has gained extra size, so any grid item placed after that line begins at the end of the gap.

Therefore you have to overlap your content above that gap with `margin-right: -20px`

```css
.container {
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(21, 1fr);
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .child {
  grid-column: 1/ 4;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `.child` next to the `column 5` i.e `column 4` plus the `20px` as you mentioned.

The easy way around is to add `margin-right: -20px` to the `child`

Hope it helps!